# I'd like a C program to accept arguments from linux command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to analyze text as an input, which will be modified and printed out based on arguments and their values entered into command prompt ( for example `./a.out -a -b 20 -c 3`), in any order and they are optional and don't have to be entered at all. How do i implement these arguments into the C code and how do i find out what values they had? 
(You can use the aforementioned -a, -b, and -c for for ease of explanation.)

Thank you.

Comment: Research the `getopt()` library call; this is designed to take the `argc` and `argv` from the command line and allow you to use them.

Comment: [getopt or argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) are the way to go on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

*(I'm not looking for votes on this one. Thanks to @SteveFriedl .)*

Since I had never heard of `getopt()` and have been guilty of writing my own parser for this kind of thing, see the example below.

Note that `getopt` appears to only accept single character argument names. For instance, you can use `-f hello.text`, but not `-filename hello.txt`. `optind` and `optarg` are (ugh) global variables declared in `unistd.h`.

(Note that it is not difficult to implement this yourself by stepping through `argv[]`, which may yield a more flexible solution.)

[Shamelessly lifted from Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getopt-function-in-c-to-parse-command-line-arguments/):

```
// copied from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getopt-function-in-c-to-parse-command-line-arguments/
// Program to illustrate the getopt() 
// function in C 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int opt; 

    // put ':' in the starting of the 
    // string so that program can 
    //distinguish between '?' and ':' 
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, “:if:lrx”)) != -1) 
    { 
        switch(opt) 
        { 
            case ‘i’: 
            case ‘l’: 
            case ‘r’: 
                printf(“option: %c\n”, opt); 
                break; 
            case ‘f’: 
                printf(“filename: %s\n”, optarg); 
                break; 
            case ‘:’: 
                printf(“option needs a value\n”); 
                break; 
            case ‘?’: 
                printf(“unknown option: %c\n”, optopt); 
                break; 
        } 
    } 

    // optind is for the extra arguments 
    // which are not parsed 
    for(; optind < argc; optind++){  
        printf(“extra arguments: %s\n”, argv[optind]); 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Then,

```
./a.out -i -f file.txt -lr -x 'hero'
```

produces

```
option: i
filename: file.txt
option: l
option: r
unknown option: x
extra arguments: hero
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you declare your main function like this,

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {}
```

Then, when you call your program from the command line,

```
./a.out 1 2 3
```

`argc` will be an int containing 4 (the number of arguments passed)

and in `argv[1]` to `argv[3]` you have pointers to the arguments 1 to 3 respectively. Whereas in `argv[0]` you have a pointer to the programs name.